# Polluted lake model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Environmental engineers are interested in identifying the volume of bodies of water in order to identify potential infiltration and evaporation rates of such a body, as well potentially identifying the time it takes for pollutants in these bodies of water to fall within acceptable standards in the event of chemical spills.
A chemical spill has taken place where 45 kg of a pollutant have been released into a lake. The maximum acceptable levels of the pollutant in water is 2 ppb (parts per billion). You have been hired in order to identify how long it will take the lake to be safe for use by the public knowing the following information:
 1% of the volume of the lake is lost through evaporation and ground infiltration daily,
 The lake is replenished with fresh water through rain and ground water at 40,000 m3 per day.
I need the differential equation for pollution level function of time t

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Please provide more context (such as what have you tried to solve the problem?). Copy-and-pasting the prompt and say "do this for me" will not get you good answers.